# convert every n rows in a matrix into a vector

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I am trying to convert a 264*264 similarity matrix into a 44 row df, such that every 6 rows in the matrix will be concatenated

Probably some version of:

as.vector(t(matrix)

Comment: Do you mean creating a new matriz with rows every 6 steps?

Comment: I think this is the exact solution @akrun offered bellow. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` into a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m1)),
       as.integer(gl(nrow(m1), 6, nrow(m1)))), function(i) c(m1[i,]))
```

and then `rbind` it to a new matrix

```
m2 <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
dim(m2)
[1]   44 1584
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(264 * 264), nrow = 264)
```

Comment: amazing! thank you! exactly the solution I was looking for